# How to launch multiple child processes that will automatically receive signals sent to parent

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel

I want to create a Bash script to launch parallel child processes.  Is there a way to do this so that the child scripts still receive signals that are sent to the parent process?

Here's roughly how I want to launch child processes, but this doesn't meet my signaling criteria.

```
for (( i=0; i<9; i++ ))
   {
   { echo $i start ; sleep 5s ; echo $i complete ; } &
   }
wait
```

Because this works automatically in a C-program (that uses `fork/exec`), I believe that it should be possible without the use of `trap`-based signal forwarding -- which itself could be interrupted before the signals are forwarded.

One workaround for this is to use `GNU-parallel`.  I don't know what it's mechanism is, but it solves this problem -- as long as you are willing to restructure your loops into `xargs` style syntax.  `GNU-parallel` does *not* solve the problem if the `--semaphore` option is used.

I think the answer is here, but I don't know how to translate it to Bash: [Signal sent to both child and parent process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12897306/86967).

Comment: I eventually developed [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17079664), but it relies on xargs (or GNU parallel) to manage the background processes.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if you are fine with using GNU Parallel - just not the xargs style.

Will it be OK to use functions?

```
doit() {
    # Trap 2 signals to show they are being given to the function
    trap 'echo you hit Ctrl-C/Ctrl-\, now exiting..; exit' SIGINT SIGQUIT
    echo $1 start
    sleep 5s
    echo $1 complete
}
export -f doit
seq 10 | parallel -u doit
```

or to avoid the pipe:

```
parallel -u doit ::: {1..10}
```

Comment: Isn't this still using the xargs style?  You have to replace the loop with a pipe -- just like with xargs.  I appreciate the capabilities of GNU Parallel, but with this question I'm really trying to discover the built-in capabilities and workings of Bash.

Comment: By the way: In [Mint 15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux_Mint_releases), parallel still requires the '--gnu' option (when installed via the standard package manager).